# React js Tree View using ul and li

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a tree view with search nodes using ul/li from JSON data in react js without using any external library.
Here is the sample of my JSON data.

-

### [ { value: "General", label: "General", count: "12 / 30", }, { value: "Accounting", label: "Accounting", count: "17 / 30", }, { value: "Labour Management", label: "Labour Management", count: "05 / 30", children: [ { value: "Labour ManagementChild", label: "Labour ManagementChild", children: [ { value: "Labour ManagementSub Child", label: "Labour ManagementSub Child", }, ], }, { value: "Labour ManagementChild2", label: "Labour ManagementChild2", }, ], }, ]

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your JSON data is stored in a variable called `tree`
and you have some random format of your data in the `li` tags
then you can go with

```
    const traverseNode = (node) => {
    return (
      <li key={node.label}>
        {node.label}:{node.value} {node.count}
        {node.children
          ? node.children.map((childNode) => (
              <ul>{traverseNode(childNode)}</ul>
            ))
          : null}
      </li>
    );
    };
    return <ul>{tree.map((node) => traverseNode(node))}</ul>;
```

Recursive solutions are helpful with such problems. I suggest taking a look again at data structures and algorithms for them ([for example on programiz](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/tree-traversal)). Your structure is not exactly a tree, but a polytree.

Comment: Glad I can be of assistance, do you mind setting your question as answered and voting the answer up, thanks :)